# Android Set ImageView Source from Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

I want to set an Image Source in Android,

XML :

```
 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:src="@drawable/malayali"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
    />
```

Java :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

  public SharedPreferences exactPreferences;


  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    exactPreferences = getSharedPreferences("details",MODE_PRIVATE);

    getSupportActionBar().hide();

    new RetriveIcon().execute();    //Api Calling & Storing value in SharedPreference

    String value = exactPreferences.getString("main_url",null);

    Log.i("from exactpreference",value);  // Working fine !!!  (http://www.exampple.com/storage/images/filename.jpeg)

   ImageView banner = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.main);
   banner.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.value));

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 }
}
```

androidStudio showing error in the below line of value as red.

```
banner.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.value));
```

ERROR:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'value'
```

How can I solve this Error ?

Comment: What is the error saying?

Comment: @Blackbelt, Error still there.

Comment: I want to set an URL to image like this http://www.exampple.com/storage/images/filename.jpeg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to load an image from your drawable folder or download one from the Internet?
This:

```
banner.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.value));
```

Will work if you have a value.png file in one of your drawable folders. If you are trying to load an image from the net (i.e. something like this: http://www.exampple.com/storage/images/filename.jpeg), you'll need to download it first and set the bitmap as an ImageView source. There are many 3rd party libraries doing this. Take a look at [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/):

```
Picasso.with(this).load(value).into(banner);
```

EDIT:
In order to add Picasso you need to update the `build.gradle` file (the one which refers to a module not project). You should have a section like this:

```
dependencies {
...
}
```

You need to add this line inside it:

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Comment: I edited my comment with some more info. Let me know if you still have troubles.

Answer (score 2):

If you are dealing with the drawable name in your `Resources` folder, then Your problem is one of those options:-

**1)You don't have the `drawable` value in your Resources.**
Make sure it exists in your resources folder.

**2)You are importing the wrong `R` in your `activity`**
Make sure you are importing your application `R` not the android one.

If your are using a Direct URL for the image. I recommend you to use [Universal Lazy Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) third party for that. All you have to do is to pass the image direct URL and the `ImageView` and it will do the job for you.

In your `Gradle` file "Module:app"

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.3'
    ....
 }
```

Comment: You cannot do it directly. Use this library to handle downloading the image from its direct URL (https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Answer (score 1):

Try this Simple code

```
 ImageView banner = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.main);
 banner.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.value);
```

But image name must be value and store in your drawable folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
String uri = "@drawable/myresource.png";

int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, getPackageName());

imageview= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Drawable res = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
imageView.setImageDrawable(res);
```

Note : This is sample code.

Answer (score 0):

You want to set your imageview's background with an online image file. You can use [this example](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/) on your project. Usage of this is very easy.

Also in your codes, you should change some lines after adding classes from the above link:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    exactPreferences = getSharedPreferences("details",MODE_PRIVATE);

    getSupportActionBar().hide();

    new RetriveIcon().execute();    //Api Calling & Storing value in SharedPreference

    String value = exactPreferences.getString("main_url",null);

    Log.i("from exactpreference",value);  // Working fine !!!  (http://www.exampple.com/storage/images/filename.jpeg)

    // ImageLoader class instance
    ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());

    ImageView banner = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.main);
    imgLoader.DisplayImage(value, 0, banner);
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: Check the link carefully, i m using this with no errors on my projects.